# Seaborn scatter plot increase the thickness of vline marker

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am generating a KDE plot and adding the data points as a scatter plot as well. I am using the vline marker "|" for this scatterplot. How can I increase the thickness of this marker. Increasing `s=200` to `s=1000` increases the height as well. Is there a way to change the thickness without changing the height?

```py
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
numberList = np.random.rand(20)
ax = sns.kdeplot(numberList)
ax = sns.scatterplot(x=numberList, y=0.1, marker='|', s=200)
plt.show()
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Use [vlines](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.vlines.html) instead?

Comment: Why not use [rugplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.rugplot.html) here?

Comment: Right! Something like this: ```for i in numberList: plt.axvline(i, 0.02,0.09, linewidth=3)```

Comment: rugplot is a good suggestion, but when I have multiple KDE plots they tend to overlap with each other.

Comment: I would also throw in a suggestion for [eventplot](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.eventplot.html) here

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Adding a parameter `linewidth=3` helped.

```py
ax = sns.scatterplot(x=numberList, y=0.1, marker="|", s=200, linewidth=3)
```

[image]